# Populating with dropdown from object values string issue

Tags: angularjs, html

I have data coming from an array of objects that each have 3 properties:

[image]

This code is put into a scope variable so that it can be used on the view.

```
            angular.forEach(result.updatedItems, function (attr) {
                $scope.suppList = attr.name;
                var test = "";
            });
```

I am now trying to access this list of text values and put it in a dropdown menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
     <li data-ng-repeat="name in suppList track by $index" style="width:100%">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

But the results that drop down only show the 1st letter of the text that is supposed to be displayed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over a string instead of an array... do following changes:

**CONTROLLER:** Remove the loop `angular.forEach` and just bind the whole list to the $scope

```
$scope.suppList = result.updatedItems;
```

**HTML**: loop over the list with `ng-repeat`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
     <li ng-repeat="supp in suppList track by $index">{{supp.name}}</li>
</ul>
```